# Querying server for files

Tags: javascript, http, tomcat, servlets, request

This is a very general question, but I hope someone can help because I'm very new to web development.

I'm trying to program a simple blog system into my website. My idea was to have a form on my website where I could type up my article, then hit upload. The article would be sent, and saved, to the server using a Java Servlet.

My question is, how would I query the server for all those articles? Is there a way to do it in JavaScript? How does the client know what files to request from the server? If anyone could point me in the write direction, I would be very grateful because I have no idea what I'm doing!

Answer (score 0):

When the articles are uploaded to the servlet, they have to be saved in some database. 
On the client side you have to provide a hyperlink or menu option to view all the articles. 
When the user clicks on the 'View All Articles' link it should call the servlet.
 The servlet has to fetch the records from the DB and put them in a list. 
This list then has to be added to a response object such as `response.setAttribute("articleList",<your_list_of_articles>)`
Now use the `requestDispatcher` object to forward the response to a jsp page. 
In the Jsp page iterate through the list and display the articles.
If you want to display only specific articles, then instead of hyperlink to the 'View All Articles' page you can provide a form which takes the title of the article as parameter and submits to the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Your must be uploading the content in the pure text format. Receive it on server side i.e Servlet. Save this text with some more data related to blog author, data and an unique id in the data base using JDBC.

Now for retrieval, first you can list all the blogs on a page with anchor tag of author name.

Anchor should be like this.

```
<a href="someservlet.do?=blogid=25">Author name </a>
```

Now on servlet you will have the blog id. use this id to retrieve the blog and return it to the browser.

This is a very rough explanation according to what you have asked.

Feel free to add more detail to question to get more specific answer.